# Can a Fujitsu LifeBook AH531 with NVIDIA GT 525M output to two external monitors simultaneously?

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card

I'm thinking of buying a Fujitsu LifeBook AH531 with a NVIDIA GeForce GT 525M. The laptop has 1 VGA port and 1 HDMI port.

I want to know if I can plug an external monitor into each port and have them work simultaneously (with the laptop display disabled).

I'm aware that the laptop will definitely not be able to output to two external monitors and the laptop display simultaneously (3 displays total).

However, from reading forums it appears that while all laptops can output to the internal monitor and one external display simultaneously, there are some laptops that cannot disable the internal display and output to two external displays.

I'm aware that there are some hardware options to add additional displays to laptops, but my question concerns if the AH531 will support this natively.

Can the AH531 with NVIDIA GeForce GT 525M output to two external displays at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this. The software is capable if you are running Windows 7, so it is entirely up to the hardware. Windows 7 (at least as far as my version is concerned) will only allow you to extend the desktop to two monitors per video card, so you are correct about not being able to use three displays at once. You could duplicate one of the displays onto the laptop screen, but this would not really serve any purpose. I hope this helps!